# Tried to make a pure css dropdown menu - the submenus are not below the main nodes

Tags: html, css

I tried to make a pure css dropdown with this tutorial: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

It's almost working but the submenus from "Test 2" and "Test 3" are below "Test 1" and not below "Test 2" and "Test 3".
Here is mine: http://jsbin.com/koyuxago/1/edit

Could you please give me a hint where my mistake is?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your submenu had left: 0px; and absolute position. I eddited your code

```
http://jsbin.com/koyuxago/2/
```

Adding relative position to #content #nav ul li woudl do the same.